# Returning an error message REST API with Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, rest, xamarin

I am developing (at least attempting anyways...) a xamarin android app with connection to API.  Below is a basic example of what I am trying to do with a Post.  I am not sure how to return the error message (not just code) back to client? I am open to a better way of doing this as long as a complete example can be provided.

API code:

```
[HttpPost("Consume")]//*
public IActionResult ConsumeInventory([FromBody] Part part)
{
    try
    {
        _repo.ConsumeInventory(part);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //ModelState.AddModelError("Error", ex.Message);
        return NotFound("Not Enough Inventory");
    }

    return Ok(part);
}
```

Client side call:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UpdatePartAsync(Part part, string post_url)
{
    string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(part);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var response = await client.PostAsync("invcount/" + post_url, new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
    {...//Would like to display "Not enough Inventory" in here}

    return response;        
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question has nothing to do with Xamarin. In this case Xamarin app is just a front-end that consumes your API.

Generally speaking, you should generalise your error responses and if needed log the exception to DB for a further analysis. JSON example:

```
{
  "Code": 1000,
  "Description": "Human readable description",
  "Id": "6a154fd3-4142-4a9c-80b5-c635e84123fa"
}
```

`Code` for internal error code in the system and `Id` for identifying the stack trace in the DB. So your end-user will get a nice human readable description and an `Id` that he could use to contact the support.

Technically, use a `ExceptionFilterAttribute` in order to catch and return a generalised error response to your clients. Reading [Global Error Handling in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://Global%20Error%20Handling%20in%20ASP.NET%20Web%20API%202) may also give you a better overview.

In your client app after you get a response from the API you can check if the response has a success status code:

```
if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    // Deserialize error message
}
```

P.S.: Stackoverflow is not a coding service, so there will be no **a complete example**. Hope you will get some ideas from my answer on how to handle it in a better way.

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Even when the API call is unsuccessful, you can [read the content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15936180/getting-content-message-from-httpresponsemessage) of the response by using `HttpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`

```
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
{
    // Would like to display "Not enough Inventory" in here}
    var resposeContent = response.Content?.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServerResponse>(resposeContent);

    // this guy will have your human-readable description or in your case, you can display the whole `result` string
    Debug.WriteLine(result.Description); 
}
```

And define you ServerResponse class as you designed your API. I regularly inherit all my API responses from the same base class so on the client side I can parse them first to check for custom directives from server (custom codes which are not always errors) message:

```
public class ServerResponse
{
     public string Code {get;set;}
     public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

ps: beware, `HttpResponseMessage.Content` could be null in certain cases.