# How to I get the detail (custom error message) returned with a bad request status code? So that I can do an ASSERT on it

Tags: testing, integration, assert, xunit, dotnet-httpclient

Hi so I am setting up some Integration tests (using Xunit) and I would like to run an Assert to check whether the correct custom error message is returned.

This is the data I need to get is in the following response see image...
detail: "Username must be unique" *Don't worry this message will be modified to be more useful later on I am just wanting to get it working first*

[Required Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SN6tK.png)

This is the current code...

```
        //Act

        response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("CompleteUserSetup", formContent);

        //Assert

        Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, response.StatusCode) ; //Bad request should be returned
        //TODO: check custom error message is correct
```

So hoping for...

ASSERT.Equal("Username must be unique", some code to get detail from response)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting content/message from HttpResponseMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15936180/getting-content-message-from-httpresponsemessage)

Comment: @Fabio Hi thank you for your suggestion it wasn't exactly what I needed but lead me on to figuring it out :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I figured out how to get the data I needed. I just needed to convert the result into an object and then I was able to pull the detail data that I needed.

```cs
var resultModel = await System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<Result>(response.Content.ReadAsStream(), JsonSerializerHelper.DefaultDeserialisationOptions);

var errorMessage = resultModel.detail;
```